# minimax algorithm not working in a two-player turn-based game

Tags: python, minimax

I am trying to use minimax algo to find a best move for a game.
The game is 2 players take turns to pick a number from a pile [0,1,2,,,8]

Winning Condition: player wins the game if the player contains three numbers and their sum is 14.

The initial game state is given by the argument like:

```
4 1 2 3 4
```

The first number indicate the total length and the following numbers are the numbers taken by player each turn. In this example the player A has [1,3] and player B has [2,4]

My problem is the algo can't give the correct answer:
Like when the input is `4 4 1 7 8` my program cannot gives the correct move: it takes `0` not `3` for next move.

```
import sys
import math

totalMoves = int(sys.argv[1])

pile = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# who are u
you = []
opponent = []
# cards in hand
playerA = []
playerB = []

# get all the cards into hand
for i in range(totalMoves):

    # save card into playerB
    if i % 2 != 0:
        playerB.append(int(sys.argv[i+2]))

    # save card into playerA
    if i % 2 == 0:
        playerA.append(int(sys.argv[i+2]))

    # remove sent card in list
    pile.remove(int(sys.argv[i+2]))


# identify which player you are
if totalMoves % 2 == 0:
    you = playerA
    opponent = playerB
else:
    you = playerB
    opponent = playerA


def find3Numbers(player):  # calcluate the card in hand is equal to 14
    arr_size = len(player)
    if (len(player) >= 3):
        for i in range(0, arr_size-2):
            for j in range(i + 1, arr_size-1):
                for k in range(j + 1, arr_size):
                    if (player[i] + player[j] + player[k] == 14):
                        return True
    else:
        return False


def isNumberLeft(board):
    if (len(board) == 0):
        return False
    else:
        return True


def evaluate(player, oppo):
    if (find3Numbers(player) == True):
        return 10
    elif (find3Numbers(oppo) == True):
        return -10
    else:
        return 0


def minimax(board, player, oppo, depth, isMax):
    score = evaluate(player, oppo)
    if (score == 10):
        return score
    if (score == -10):
        return score
    if (isNumberLeft(board) == False):
        return 0
    if (isMax):
        best = -math.inf
        for card in board:
            player.append(card)
            board.remove(card)
            best = max(best, minimax(board, player, oppo, depth+1, not isMax))
            board.append(card)
            player.remove(card)
        return best
    else:
        best = +math.inf
        for card in board:
            oppo.append(card)
            board.remove(card)
            best = min(best, minimax(board, player, oppo, depth+1, not isMax))
            board.append(card)
            oppo.remove(card)
        return best


def bestMove():
    bestScore = -math. inf
    bestNum = -math.inf
    for card in pile:
        you.append(card)
        pile.remove(card)
        score = minimax(pile, you, opponent, 0, False)

        pile.append(card)
        you.remove(card)
        if (bestScore < score):
            bestNum = card
            bestScore = score

    return bestNum


you.append(bestMove())
```

Comment: What sort of debuggin have you made? Does it give the expected result from the evaluation function? Does it update the best score accordingly? Where is the problem more exactly? To get good answers you need to do some work yourself and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.. The evaluation function was fine. It can calculate the correct evaluation value of a board. And best score can also be updated. The problem is I don't know why the program would give the wrong estimation.